# How do you get the text the user entered into the search Bar?

Tags: xcode, search, uisearchbar, searchbar

I want to be able to get the text the user entered into a search bar, and compare the words in an array.  But i'm not sure how to get the text from the search bar, I know in java its just getText.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you named the `UISearchBar` just `searchBar`, you can retrieve the text with

```
searchBar.text
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`. There it was empty. Where can you retrieve this value?

Answer (score 2):

**In SearchBar Delegate method, you can get searchbar text**

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSString *str = searchBar.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
```